Split column in csv file in batch scripting without using delims
I want to split a column in a .CSV file like this: ,A,B,,C,D,E.
Before the 1st comma, there is a blank cell, and between the 3rd and 4th cell, there is a blank.
When I run a batch scripting code to split by comma, in cell A1 I get 'A', but in cell A1 there is no value, it is blank. This is because I split by comma.
Is there any way to split without using delimiters? Please, can anyone help with this problem?

There are no 'columns' in a CSV file. There are no 'cells' in a CSV file. There is no 'A1' type field and record identifiers in a CSV file. The problem you have described is not one with your written and submitted programming code, and is therefore off topic. We have a search facility you can use to locate code to adapt for your specific project. We do not write code for you, do your reference work, or tell you how to complete your own tasks. Please take time to read through the content and linked pages withi [ask].

This works:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "row=,A,B,,C,D,E"
set "i=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!row:^,^= ^
%Don't remove this line%
!^") do (
   set "col=%%a"
   set /A i+=1
   echo A!i!="!col:~0,-1!"
)

Output:
A1=""
A2="A"
A3="B"
A4=""
A5="C"
A6="D"
A7=""


Don't try to mess with the delimiters, mess with the tokens instead: quote each one, so there are no "empty tokens" any more:
@echo off
set "string=,A,B X,,C,D,E"
echo quoting each token: "%string:,=","%" (even works with spaces within a token)
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (""%string:,=","%"") do (
  echo with quotes    %%a-%%b-%%c-%%d-%%e-%%f 
  echo without quotes %%~a-%%~b-%%~c-%%~d-%%~e-%%~f
)

